# I want to filter data from the output

Tags: node.js

I have data stored in this

```
console.log(inventory.filter(findData));
```

this has the data like name,address,contact,etc.. but I am interested in just showing the name and contacts.

I tried storing this console.log in var p and then writing the code as

`console.log(p.name,p.contact);`

but this does not work

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet of what you're trying to do because from your question it seems as if you are trying to store console.log itself into a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use lodash and do something like

```
var _ = require('lodash');
console.log(_.map(inventory.filter(findData), (d) => { 
                                     return {name: d.name, contacts: d.contacts}
                                    }))
```